# Template substitution for function names

Tags: c++

I'm using a third party C++ library which has a json parsing class that has 
different functions like this:

```
GetInt  
GetBool
GetString
GetDouble
```

I'd like to write a utility function that can access this class. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
class <template T>
class MyClass {
static T getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string &key) {
   if(someObj[key].IsDouble())
       return someObj[key].GetDouble();
   else if (someObj[key].IsString())
       return someObj[key].GetString();
   // ... (for other types)

} 
}
```

The caller of this class will hold the correct return type.

However this is ugly. Is there any way (using macro substitution for example) I can avoid the if conditions? The third party class has IsXXTypeXX and corresponding GetXXTypeXX functions (where XXTypeXX is Int, Double,String or Bool).

I know the return type when I call the function for eg:

```
int i = getValue(someObj, "intKey");
string s = getValue(someObj, "strKey");
```

So I dont need the if conditions at all. Ideally I would look to have something so 
I would be able to do this:

```
int i = MyClass<int>::getValue(someObj, "intKey"); 

string s = MyClass<string>::getValue(someObj, "strKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a bunch of static Get functions (GetInt/GetDouble...) that validates the input, returns the appropriate type result and throws an exception if it isn't that type?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can achieve the public interface that you've outlined there but that would involve very ugly looking template specialization.
It would probably be better if you just had a bunch of static functions instead. Here is what template specialization would look like:

```
template <typename T> class MyClass { 
    static T getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string &key) {
       // handle types that you didn't specialize for
    } 
};
template <> class MyClass <string> { 
    static string getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string &key) {
       return someObj[key].GetString();
    } 
};
template <> class MyClass <int> { 
    static int getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string &key) {
       return someObj[key].GetInt();
    } 
};
//..
```

Comment: Template specialization is a good solution here, as it provides compile-time type resolution mechanism, instead of run-time type checks and branching.

Comment: Thanks. I've not used template specialization before. I'll use this.

Answer (score 1):

Skeleton key for software engineering: add an intermediate layer.

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using std::string;

class Proxy {
public:
  enum Type {
    Int,
    Bool,
    String,
    Double
  };
  Type type;
  int i;
  bool b;
  string s;
  double d;
  operator int() const {
    assert(type == Int);
    return i;
  }
  operator bool() const {
    assert(type == Bool);
    return b;
  }
  operator string() const {
    assert(type == String);
    return s;
  }
  operator double() const {
    assert(type == Double);
    return d;
  }
  Proxy(int i) : type(Int), i(i) {}
  Proxy(bool b) : type(Bool), b(b) {}
  Proxy(string s) : type(String), s(s) {}
  Proxy(double d) : type(Double), d(d) {}
}; // class Proxy

Proxy getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string &key) {
  if (someObj[key].IsDouble())
    return someObj[key].GetDouble();
  else if (someObj[key].IsString())
    return someObj[key].GetString();
   //... (for other types)
}

int main() {
  int i = getValue(someObj, "intKey"); // if type does not match, a exception will be thrown.
  string s = getValue(someObj, "strKey");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed won't compile. You can't in the same function return a `double`, a `string`, and an `int`. What you'd have to do it specialize for each return type, and then call only the function for that type:

```
template <>
class MyClass<int> getValue(ThirdPartyClass someObj, const string& key) {
    if(someOjb[key].IsInt()) return someObj[key].GetInt();
    else { /* Maybe throw an exception */ }
};
```

and repeat for each type.

Now, you're probably thinking, "this is silly, how come I have to specialize each type?" That's because your JSON library is using type erasure, so you have to check the type at runtime. The only way to save yourself the work is if the library provides a templated `get`.

If you want, you could create a macro to stamp these instantiations out. It would take advantage of the `#` ([stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)) and `##` ([concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)) features of the preprocessor. It'll probably be clearer to just write them out.

Comment: Yeah, the code I gave was just an example of what I was thinking, not the actual code. Thanks for pointing the mistake :) And thanks for suggestion of concatenation (wasn't familiar with that)